How to suppress an error message I got using curve_fit function?
How can I suppress the error message:
Intel MKL ERROR: Parameter 4/5 was incorrect on entry to DLASCL.
I get the error while using curve_fit() function in Spider 5.x (Python 3.11).
I know that the results I get by the function may be inaccurate and I am handling it in some way.
Thanks.
I know that the original code was written in Fortran but it is more than 30 years that I have not worked with Fortran and have no idea what to do.
I do not think it can be suppressed using @ error suppression (at least I do not know how).
